# Backbone.js: Event that is triggered once as a result of Collection.fetch()?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a View that listens for the 'add' event on a collection, upon which it calls the render() method:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(myCollection, 'add', this.render);
  myCollection.fetch();
}
```

But the render() method gets called multiple times. Is there a way to call the render() method for a "batch load"?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) event? Note that the default has changed so that a [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) no longer triggers a reset unless you pass in `{reset: true}`, for example `myCollection.fetch({reset:true});`.

Comment: @Jack I tried what you said, myCollection.fetch({reset:true}), but the render() method didn't even get invoked.

Comment: Did you switch from listening to the *add* event to listen to the *reset* event? `this.listenTo(myCollection, 'reset', this.render);`

Answer (score 0):

Jack was right. In order to detect a batch load of a collection you need to listen to a 'reset' event and pass the {reset: true} option to the collection's fetch method. Here is an example code:

```
    var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: SomeModel,

        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('test')

    });

    var someCollection = new SomeCollection();

    var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(someCollection, 'reset', this.render);
        },

        render: function() {
            console.log(someCollection.toJSON());
        }

    });

    var someView = new SomeView();

    someCollection.fetch({reset:true});
```

By the way, I checked to make sure that the 'reset' event is trigger AFTER the collection has been filled.

Comment: Glad to help, you probably should indicate that this worked for you by accepting your answer.

Comment: @Jack I tried but it doesn't let me to accept my own answer.

Comment: You might need to wait a day or so before it allows you to self-accept.